# How to modify the code so that the output becomes rectangle in Processing application

Tags: java, processing

This is the code.

```
//Bergen, NORWAY
String LAT = "60.39097752046264";   
String LONG = "5.310058600685323";

//Kuala Lumpur, MALAYSIA
//String LAT = "3.1573573549026794";   
//String LONG = "101.71161402234756";

String[] month = {"01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
                  "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"};

JSONObject myData;
int[] dayLengthInSeconds = new int[12];
float twentyfourhoursInSeconds = 0.0;

void setup(){  
  size(500, 500);
  
  for (int i=0; i<12; i++){
    String DATE = "2022-" + month[i] + "-15";
    String URL = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org" +
                 "/json?lat=" + LAT + "&lng=" + LONG + "&date=" + DATE;
    
    myData = loadJSONObject(URL);
    JSONObject results = myData.getJSONObject("results");
    String myDayLength = results.getString("day_length");
    String[] thisData = split(myDayLength, ":");
    int HH = int(thisData[0]);
    int MM = int(thisData[1]);
    int SS = int(thisData[2]);
    
    dayLengthInSeconds[i] = HH*60*60 + MM*60 + SS;
  }
  
  twentyfourhoursInSeconds = 24*60*60;
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(8);
  
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++){
    float resize = 100 + (i/12.0) * 300;
    
    stroke(200);
    float start = 0.0;
    float stop = radians((dayLengthInSeconds[i]/twentyfourhoursInSeconds)*360.0);
    arc(width*0.5, height*0.5, resize, resize, start, start+stop);
    
    float nightLengthInSeconds = twentyfourhoursInSeconds - dayLengthInSeconds[i];
    stroke(32);
    start = stop;
    stop = radians((nightLengthInSeconds/twentyfourhoursInSeconds)*360.0);
    arc(width*0.5, height*0.5, resize, resize, start, start+stop);
  }
}
```

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abtwK.png)

I wonder how do I modify this code so that the ouput becomes rectangle with blue and yellow colour instead of circle with black and grey as shown in the output.

I ran this code on application called Processing.

Hope someone can help me.

I already try to do replace the radians() and arc() with rect() but got errors.

I'm new to this application, I might be wrong.

Comment: Whose code is this? What is the source?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It sounds like you want to draw points along a square (or maybe rectangle ?) but instead of the full shape, only reveal areas in between two angles (similar to `arc()` but instead of a circle sector, rendering a "square sector" ? (reminds me of the life bar in the classic video game The Last Ninja). If so, one idea could be to compute the 4 corners of a square, use `lerp()` to find the points in between (constraining/mapping only to the start / stop angle) and mapping the angle to `lerp()`'s interpolation parameter (`t`). Another option could be rendering to `PGraphics` and using `mask()`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

The following code will draw rectangles for the 'stop' and 'nightLengthInSeconds' data.  I have no idea if this is what you're looking for.

```
void draw(){
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(2.0);  
  for(int i=0; i<12; i++){   
    float start = 0.0;
    float stop = dayLengthInSeconds[i]/twentyfourhoursInSeconds;
   // println("stop = ",dayLengthInSeconds[i]/twentyfourhoursInSeconds);
   fill(0,0,255);
   rect(start, 30+i*30, stop*100, 10);
    float nightLengthInSeconds = twentyfourhoursInSeconds - dayLengthInSeconds[i];
   // println("nightLengthInSeconds = ",nightLengthInSeconds);
    fill(255,0,0);
    rect(start, 40+i*30, nightLengthInSeconds/1000, 10);
  }
}
```